# Object [object Object] has no method 'listview' when using jquery to add items to list

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I'm trying to dynamically add items into a `<ul>` via jquery, and have followed documentation [here](http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH11.php)

I seem to be struggling with the `listview` invocation...

This is my HTML :

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="tweets">
        <li><a href="astra.html">Astra</a></li>
        <li><a href="ford.html">Ford</a></li>
        <li><a href="triumph.html">Triump</a></li>
        <li><a href="chevrolet.html">Chevrolet</a></li>
        <li><a href="dodge.html">Dodge</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This is my Jquery:

```
$("#tweets").append("<li>Nissan</li>");
                $("#tweets").listview("refresh");
```

And this is the error I see in Chrome JS console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listview'

This is what I see in the browser :

[image]

I've tried calling listview both with and without the "refresh", both seem to give the same error, what am I doing wrong?

I've looked at ~5 previous SO questions, but none of their answers have helped.

**EDIT**:

I already have the following in the `<head>` elements :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT 2**

The above javascript is being execute after a button is clicked, not sure if that has any effect...

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="getTweets()">GetTweets</a>
```

JS:

```
function getTweets() {
// some static value for now, to get it working...
    $("#tweets").append("<li>Nissan</li>");

try {
                    $('#tweets').listview('refresh');
                } catch(e) {
                    $('#tweets').listview();
                }
}
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery Mobile correctly? Your error suggests that it hasn't been loaded.

Comment: Check that you include the jquery mobile and write your code within `$(document).bind('pageinit')`.

Comment: I've already included the jquery script references :S

Comment: @thecodeparadox Don't use document.ready(), use $(document).bind('pageinit') instead http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Your missing the `a` tag from your `append`, other then that your code seems to be correct.

Comment: [Nope, I cannot recreate this issue with the code you've provided.](http://jsfiddle.net/mxELn/)

Comment: @James.Elsey are you using $(document).bind('pageinit') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your listview is not initiated the first time you add an item. Try this, for example:

```
try {
    $('#tweets').listview('refresh');
} catch(e) {
    $('#tweets').listview();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that still gives the same behaviour.. :S

Comment: =/ I guess you're doing it too soon somehow. Change the `document.ready()` for `$(document).bind('pageinit')` or other variant recommended at jquerymobile

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that jQuery Mobile is not defined.
is it included before the jQuery?
Do you overrun jQuery somehow?
I'll need more code in order to help you with this problem.